# Is there a newbie forum?

Tags: discussion

Is there a forum for complete newbies like myself, where we can ask the really ignorant questions, like how to paint the surface of an object or make objects move together as one etc?

I just started today and I feel a bit awkward asking these really basic questions in here, but figuring everything out by myself will take forever. There's just so many options...

Thanks.

Comment: with google or with the search tool you may find that your question has already been answered, for example, how to paint the surface of and object: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65853/can-i-paint-on-my-objects

Comment: This is the right place, to get help there are a few guidlines:  state your question clearly and ask one question at the time. Note that many questions have been answered already, so feel free to use the search function at the top of the page.

Comment: There is also [Blender Artists](https://blenderartists.org) if you don't wan't to put the research effort first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resources for Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender)

Comment: You can also ask questions in our [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm) or on the [#blender irc channel](http://irc.lc/freenode/blender)